# The Output Window always freezes during uploading or saving files (Open CV on python running on a Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I made a motion detector solely software-based by referring a few books and then adding my own code. The added code saves a frame of the detected motion locally on the Raspberry Pi and also uploads the same to my Google Drive. Another set of code, sends an email to my email-address informing me of the motion detected.

The problem is that when the file is being saved and uploaded, the Open CV output window freezes until the above processes finish. I tried multiprocessing and multi-threading on python but it didn't help. Is there any way I could improve my logic in a way that it doesn't freeze the output window?

EDIT : The issue was somewhat fixed by removing join() from the two processes. There is a very slight lag but I think that's good enough. Thanks to everyone who replied :)

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import smtplib

# make count 0
count = 0

def sf(t2):
    cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Desktop/StoredImages/frame%d.jpg" % count, t2)


# 'google drive authentication' stuff
gauth = GoogleAuth()
# try to load saved client credentials
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    # authenticate if not there
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    # Refresh them if expired
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    # Initialize the saved creds
    gauth.Authorize()
# Save the current credentials to a file
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


def upload_file():
    file1 = drive.CreateFile({'parent':'/home/pi/Desktop/StoredImages/'})
    file1.SetContentFile('/home/pi/Desktop/StoredImages/frame%d.jpg' % count)
    file1.Upload()

# 'sending an email' stuff
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login("Removed Intentionally","Removed Intentionally")
msg = "Motion Detected! For more details check your Drive."

# capture Video from the camera module
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# stores the present date and time
lastUploaded = datetime.datetime.now()

# kernel is created for the dilation process
k = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8) # creates a 3X3 Matrix filled with ones and
                            # has the data type uint8 (unsigned integer)
                            # which can contain values from 0 to 255

# first two subsequent frames captured
t0 = cap.read()[1]
t1 = cap.read()[1]

# initially motion detected 0 times
motionCounter = 0

while True:
    # difference between two subsequent frames
    d=cv2.absdiff(t1,t0)

    # stores present date and time
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

    # converting difference to grayscale
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(d,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # grayscale converted to gaussian blur
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey,(3,3),0)

    # gaussian blur converted to binary image
    ret, th = cv2.threshold(blur, 15, 155, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # dilating the image before using the contour function
    dilated = cv2.dilate(th,k,iterations=2)

    # contour function to find edges
    _, contours, heierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # copying the original frame to a temporary frame for display
    t2 = t0

    # drawing green edges around the area with movement
    cv2.drawContours(t2, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)

    # showing output in a new window
    cv2.imshow('Output',t2)

    # going through each and every contour in the image
    for c in contours:
        # if contour is lesser than a threshold size, ignore
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 5000:
            continue

        # if motion occurred after 2 secs
        if (timestamp - lastUploaded).seconds >= 2.0:
            motionCounter += 1

            # if 8 motions occured in 2 secs
            if motionCounter >= 8:
                # write to a temporary file location using threads
                new_process = Process(target=sf, args=(t2,))
                new_process.start()
                new_process.join()

                # upload the temporary pic to Google drive using threads
                new_process = Process(target=upload_file)
                new_process.start()
                new_process.join()

                # sending a mail about motion detected
                server.sendmail("Removed Intentionally","Removed Intentionally",msg)

                # increasing count by 1 and resetting everything
                count=count+1
                lastUploaded = timestamp
                motionCounter = 0

    # making the next frame the previous and reading a new frame
    t0 = t1
    t1 = cap.read()[1]

    # esc key breaks the entire loop
    if cv2.waitKey(5) == 27:
        break

# stops the video stream and exits the window
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# stops the email server connection
server.quit()
```

Comment: What was the program logic that you used when you tried multithreading ?

Comment: If your camera is on the USB, did you know that the ethernet connection on your Pi is actually on USB as well? (This is likely one reason that Pi doesn't attempt gigabit ethernet because USB 2.0 can't go that fast). If you capture just to disk on the Pi, does doing an extensive file transfer over the network in/out of the Pi stall the video?

Comment: @barny I haven't tried that. The local saved file is only temporary though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you used the multiprocessing in a wrong way. Your code

```
# write to a temporary file location using threads
new_process = Process(target=sf, args=(t2,))
new_process.start()
new_process.join()
```

will actually create and start a process, but then it will also wait for it (`new_process.join()`) to finish. So basically you want to start a parallel running process, but then you wait for it to finish.
Better would be to create and start the processes at the beginning of your program and wait for them to finish at the very end of your program.

Also create a queue for each process (also in the multiprocessing module).

Each process should run in an endless loop and wait for a queue. In your main thread, you feed each process' queue with what it should do (store a file locally, store file remotely)

At the end of your program, you should send your processes a final indication to leave their endless loop, so your `new_process.join()` statement in the main thread will pick up the fact, that the processes have ended.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm a noob to multiprocessing or multithreading in python. Could you please write an example code to explain it?

Comment: When I removed the join() line, the problem was greatly reduced. The lag is very very less and its bearable now. Thanks :)

Comment: If your main() exits without join()ing all its threads you risk them dying mid-operation.